# Using map of sets in resource creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, terraform

I have a terraform map of set objects as given below

```
variable "BName" {
 type = string
 }
variable "type_names" {
 type = map(object({
 name   = string
 type   = string
 stream = string
 grp    = optional(string)
 }))
}
```

I'm also trying to use the type_name in the following resource. **How we can refer the value from map of sets during the resource creation**

```
resource "azure_resource" "reso" {
  id = az_resource.B_Name.id
  name       = var.type_names.name

 }
resource "az_resource" "B_Name" {
  name        = var.BName
```

}

**How I can pass this value in terraform.tfvars file to create following resource**. Now I'm trying to pass  the following way

```
 BName  = "Test"
 type_names =   {
   name = "cooper"
   type = "senior"
   stream=  "developer"
   grp   =  "Mid"
}
{
   name = "Mike"
   type = "Junior"
   stream=  "tester"
   grp   =  "entry"
}
```

Comment: Could you please update your example variable values? They are of type `object`, and not `map(set(object))`. Also, if you can use `set(object)` or `map(object)` instead, those would both be easier.

Comment: @MattSchuchard i have updated the variables. Could you help

Comment: If you have `map(object)`, then you can just use the `for_each` meta-argument normally: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html. Is that not working for you?

Comment: but how i could give the values in terraform.tfvars. Wondering whether  the one i given in question is the correct format

Comment: Ok I see now that the documentation example for `map` is wrong. I think at this point I can just write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating multiple resources with a single definition with a `map(object)` variable input, there exists a general algorithm and pattern. First, we need the variable structure definition from the declaration. For your example, we have:

```
variable "type_names" {
  type = map(object({
    name   = string
    type   = string
    stream = string
    grp    = optional(string)
  }))
}
```

where I assume the use of the experimental feature for optional object keys given the appearance of the keyword `optional`. In this situation, it is helpful for the resource to have a descriptive identifier. That would most likely be the `name`, so we can remove it from the `object` value and refactor it to be the `map` key. Updated definition with an example `default` that conforms to the type definition would be:

```
variable "type_names" {
  type = map(object({
    type   = string
    stream = string
    grp    = optional(string)
  }))
  default = {
    "cooper" = {
      type   = "senior"
      stream = "developer"
      grp    = "Mid"
    },
    "Mike" = {
      type   = "Junior"
      stream = "tester"
      grp    = "entry"
    }
  }
}
```

We can then easily use this to manage multiple resources with a single definition and input variable. Since the example resource in the question is using different keys than the provided variable possesses, we will modify the example resource slightly:

```
resource "azure_resource" "this" {
  for_each = var.type_names

  # value is the object, so we access object values with standard `.key` syntax
  name   = each.key
  type   = each.value.type
  stream = each.value.stream
  grp    = each.value.grp
}
```

and the namespace of each resource will be `azure_resource.this["<key>"]` e.g. `azure_resource.this["Mike"]`, and you can access its attributes normally.

Comment: Thank you @MattSchuchard 
But I'm getting an error.
This default value is not compatible with the variable's type constraint: element "cooper": attribute "name" is required. Shall i add name also to the default map

Comment: @tjdoubts Please use the config I provided in the answer and read the explanation for the config. My answer does not throw that error.